# Bulk add new field to ALL documents in an elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to add a new field to ALL documents in an index without pulling down the document and pushing it back up (this will take about a day).  Is it possible to use the _BULK api to achieve this?

I have also researched the update_by_query plugin, and it seems to would take just as long as pulling them down and pushing them back myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the bulk API supports [updates](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) which can add a new field using a partial document or script. To iterate through your document ids do a [scan and scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html) with the [fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-fields.html) parameter set to an empty array.

Comment: Hi all the links in the answer are landing e to the elastic home page. Can you please add the proper link?