# Class cannot be resolved. It is directly referenced from required .class files

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Hi I am trying to execute Update by query,i am using this code

```
UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder ubqrb = UpdateByQueryAction.INSTANCE.newRequestBuilder(client);

Script script = new Script("ctx._source.RELATIONSHIP_DEPTH = doc['"+AggregateValue_First+"'].value*doc['"+AggregateValue_Second+"'].value");

ubqrb.source(indexName)
    .script(script)
    .filter(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery())
    .get();
```

But I am getting these errors:

> The type
>   org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.IndicesReplicationOperationRequestBuilder
>   cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from       required
>   .class files
>     - The method source(String) is undefined for the type UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder

I have used the reindex.jar and I build my node like this:

```
node = nodeBuilder().clusterName(clusterName).client(true).node();
client = node.client();
```

I am using elasticsearch-2.3.4.jar and when I'm typing like this, I don't get any error:

```
UpdateByQueryClientWrapper ubqrb = new UpdateByQueryClientWrapper(client);
ubqrb.prepareUpdateByQuery().setScript("ctx._source.RELATIONSHIP_DEPTH = doc['"+AggregateValue_First+"'].value"+operator+"doc['"+AggregateValue_Second+"'].value");
```

The problem arises when I am using the query, which version of jar should I use for `UpdateByQuery`?

Comment: Do you only need to run this code once to add your field? If yes, why not simply running this update-by-query through Sense or curl?

Comment: The things is i am building a class which would automatically calculate the value and create the field for all documents ,essentially like a formula ,that is why i need this code,moreover i am using it inside a function so whenever the function is claled it will create a new field with new calculated value.

Comment: UpdateByQuery is the way to go for your use case, but I don't understand why you're getting your error. It seems you're using libraries that are not compatible with the version of ES you're running. Which version of ES are you running?

Comment: The version is  ES-2.3.4 and JRE 1.8

Comment: Thanks anyways Val

Comment: Val Can we use queries with bulk???i mean to ask how do we do this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28329523/bulk-add-new-field-to-all-documents-in-an-elasticsearch-index

Comment: Val i have modified the question,can you please check?

Comment: The error means your dependency handling is not correct. Are you using Maven or equivalent or just manually adding required .jar files to classpath?

Comment: I am manually adding jar files , im not using maven or any other dependency

Comment: @t0mppa what should i do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The type org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.IndicesReplicationOperationRequestBuilder cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files - The method source(String) is undefined for the type UpdateByQueryRequestBuilder

What this means is that a class in either your own code  or in one of your direct dependencies is trying to use the class `org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.IndicesReplicationOperationRequestBuilder`, which is currently not part of any .jar file that you have currently added as a dependency for your application.

With a bit of Googling (*) it can be found that this class used to be part of elasticsearch.jar, for instance in elasticsearch-1.5.1.jar.

Thus, you should go through your dependency setup and make sure that the versions of dependencies (and classes called on your own code) you're using are consistent with each other.

A build tool like Maven, Ivy, Gradle or Sbt for instance will make this a bit simpler. Via manual handling of dependencies it's more work, but still doable.

---

(*) How to find this out:

1. [Search for the class in question](https://www.google.fi/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=IndicesReplicationOperationRequestBuilder)
2. [Open a link to JavaDocs](http://xbib.org/elasticsearch/1.5.1/apidocs/org/elasticsearch/action/support/replication/IndicesReplicationOperationRequestBuilder.html). See the version of package this page is describing.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Tomppa it worked , the newer version was missing the index replication, i just set the dependency to the older version ,now its working, thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: And now my reindex and elasticsearch jars are conflicting and im getting jar hell ,will this resolve if i give as as maven dependency?

Comment: A build tool will make life simpler, but is not a cure-it-all. Basically you will still need to make sure that you use compatible versions of different components (but usually this can be solved by searching information from Internet).